# D3.js: Centering content inside a responsive pie chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

--> [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6q7rqkw/4/) <--

I have a fully responsive pie chart (i.e. it resizes and scales both horizontally and vertically).  How could I go about centering some external content?  For instance, an icon and some text.

In the Fiddle above, the goal is basically to get the tan circle to fit within the constraints of the SVG's inner radius, and not get an oblong shape when resizing.

I would prefer this to be a CSS solution but I'm not entirely sure that's possible.

```
.chart-content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: tan;
  border-radius: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using SVG foreign objects? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject